# Join multiple NURBS circles without collapsing circles/losing positions?

Tags: modeling, objects, nurbs-surface

I'm trying to join and fill multiple NURBS circle surfaces (similar to the YouTube video here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kGmh9r6pkE) but when I join my circles, they collapse into one circle, as opposed to keeping each circle's unique location.

Any help appreciated!

Blender file before joining:  [image]

Blender file after joining:  [image]

Comment: I have never really used Blender's NURBS objects,m but it looks like this is not supported somehow. I have tested with other fresh newly added NURBS primitives, and joining them always seems results in squashed 2D shapes, collapsed in the Z axis. Either this is a bug or a limitation of Blender's NURBS system.

Comment: I noticed something, after they are joined, going into edit mode and trying to move it in the z axis wont work. Only if you change the z-axis in the properties editor, will it move in the z axis. If you change it in the properties shelf, it wont budge. I seen this behavior some-wear, I forget where.

Comment: A possible workaround is to go into edit mode as soon as the first one is created and create the new circles within edit mode.

Comment: I submitted a bug report on your behalf https://developer.blender.org/T53717

Comment: Just curious, for what purpose do you need to use NURBS?

Comment: I was trying to make a hat (similar to the youtube video linked in the original  query). I'm sure I can find another way to create it though... just have to do some poking around. Appreciate any advice!